# What would cause the completion percentage of a command or process to change when executing it a second time in the same environment?

Tags: command-line, terminal, makefile

While attempting to install OpenCV I noticed that my first attempt aborted only 47% complete.

Once I executed "make -j8" again the percentage elevated to 60% completion.

1st attempt:

```
make -j8
Scanning dependencies of target zlib
Scanning dependencies of target libjasper
Scanning dependencies of target libjpeg
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/deflate.c.o
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.c.o
[  1%] [  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapimin.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_cm.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzwrite.c.o
[  1%] [  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inflate.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapistd.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/infback.c.o
[  1%] [  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inftrees.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jccoefct.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_debug.c.o
[  1%] [  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inffast.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jccolor.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/trees.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcdctmgr.c.o
[  1%] [  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_getopt.c.o
Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jchuff.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/uncompr.c.o

.....


[ 47%] Built target opencv_calib3d
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

2nd attempt:

```
make -j8
[  2%] Built target zlib
[  7%] [ 11%] Built target libjasper
Built target libjpeg
[ 13%] Built target libpng
[ 18%] Built target libtiff
[ 21%] Built target opencv_core
[ 30%] Built target IlmImf
[ 30%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 32%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 37%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 37%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 39%] Built target opencv_video
[ 41%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 44%] [ 45%] Built target opencv_objdetect
Built target opencv_features2d
[ 45%] [ 45%] [ 45%] [ 45%] [ 45%] [ 45%] [ 45%] [ 47%] Built target opencv_nonfree
Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/precomp.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_func.cpp.o
Built target opencv_calib3d
Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_perf.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_gtest.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_arrtest.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_contrib
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_legacy
[ 47%] Building CXX object modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/adaptiveskindetector.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/3dtracker.cpp.o

...

[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/prewarp.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/pyrsegmentation.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/scanlines.cpp.o
[ 59%] [ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/segment.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/snakes.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/spilltree.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/stereogc.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/subdiv2.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/testseq.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/texture.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/trifocal.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/vecfacetracking.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object modules/legacy/CMakeFiles/opencv_legacy.dir/src/video.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib
[ 60%] Built target opencv_legacy
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After several more attemps, I reached 72% completion and any further efforts returned the exact same results:

```
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/precomp.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_arrtest.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_perf.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_func.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_gtest.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why should your progress change at all if you run the same command in the same environment?

Comment: No idea. Some process which make is calling (which can literally be anything) is returning 2 when 0 indicates success. The reason it has went past that point the second time is because the target file(s) for the rule had been created. Though not necessarily correctly, possibly leading to the final set of errors. Try the `-d` option to `make` to see what it is actually up to. If this isn't enough, check out `remake` which is good for debugging Makefiles.

Comment: You might wanna tone down the parellelization in your makeflags a bit there, @Les. Dunno if that's the issue, but make -j8 can really trip up a compiler on a big job if the code isn't properly optimized for it.

Comment: @mikeserv could that be the issue?? Please explain (chat perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

`make` (witout using `-k`) stops at the first error. When starting `make` again it calculates the dependencies again ommiting already made stuff and if something other than the command causing the previous error is the 1st thing to do, it may succeed and so generate progress until the next error ist hit or the previosly seen error strikes again...

Repeating this will somewhen reach a point where starting `make` again and again will not generate progress because all things left to do depend on actions causing an error.

`make -k` will run as far as possible by not stopping for errors. Try this twice and there should not be further progress in the 2nd run.